# What are the lengths of common datatypes?

Tags: c++, types, 64-bit, 32-bit

How many bytes would an `int` contain and how many would a `long` contain in C++?

Please provide some information about the 32-bit and the 64-bit computers, and the differences.

Answer (score 7):

See [the wikipedia article about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 7):

it is platform and compiler specific. do sizeof(int) and sizeof(long) in c or c++.

Answer (score 5):

(I assume you're talking about C/C++)

It's implementation dependant, but this rule should be always valid:

sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said endlessly, it depends on the compiler you're using (and even the compiler options that you select).

However, in practice, with compilers for many 32-bit machines, you will find:-

- char: 8 bit
- short: 16 bit
- int:  32-bit
- long: 32-bit
- long long: 64-bit ( if supported)

The C standard basiucally says that a *long* can't be shorter than an *int* which can't be shorter than a *short*, etc...

For 64-bit CPUs, those often don't change, but you **`MUST`** beware that pointers and ints are frequently not the same size:

```
 sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*)
```

Comment: Actually it does change for 64 bit Unix: long is 64-bit there.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler.

On a 32 bit system, both int and long contain 32 bits.
On a 16 bit system, int is 16 bits and long is 32.

There are other combinations!

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the hardware your using. on 32-bit platforms it is typically 4 bytes for both int and long. in C you can use the sizeof() operator to find out.

```
int intBytes;
long longBytes;
intBytes= sizeof(int);
longBytes = sizeof(long);
```

I'm not sure if long becomes 8 bytes on 64-bit architectures or if it stays as 4.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your compiler. And your language, for that matter. Try asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

That depends greatly on the language you are using.

In C, "int" will always be the word length of the processor. So 32 bits or 4 bytes on a 32 bit architecture.